# ASUS X553M laptop with DOS pre-installed: how to install windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, laptop

I bought a new ASUS X553M laptop with DOS pre-installed, I am trying to install windows xp but getting error "The BIOS in this system is not fully ACPI compliant. STOP : 0x0000007e"

Comment: Windows XP is EOL. Why would you use it? 0x7e means SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, by the way. Nothing about ACPI there.

Comment: stop: 0x0000007e (0xc0000005, 0xf73b9d66, 0xf78d9ea0, 0xf78d9b9c)                                                   acpi.sys - address f73b9d66 base at f73ae000, datestamp 480252b1

Comment: I would strongly recommend you don't try to put XP on... Why not Buy Windows 8 for less than £100, install that and then install Windows XP as a virtual machine using, say, VirtualBox?

Answer (score -1):

When you get to press <kbd>F6</kbd> then press <kbd>F7</kbd> to skip checking ACPI.